# Android ICS : JNI error attempt to use stale local reference 0x1

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, java-native-interface

After upgrading my phone to android 4.03 ics  my game dosent open anymore ,it just closes without any error messege on deviCe and with this  on eclipse

```
04-02 16:55:27.672: E/dalvikvm(26884): JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1
04-02 16:55:27.672: E/dalvikvm(26884): VM aborting
```

My game is mainly writen in java  but some parts are in c and thats were i think the
problem  is (not very hard to figure out since its saying  JNI ERROR :) )

Of course  i dont know where the problem is so i dont give any code

I didnt had this problem on android 2.3

I dont know if it helps but i get this error too sometimes

```
04-02 16:55:26.061: E/Adreno200-ES11(26884): <qglDrvAPI_glTexImage2D:1913>: GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While Ernest's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9978102/130066) is technically correct, a stale local reference to something like 0x1 should hint you that the Java VM is trying to use something that's not a Java object as a Java object.

For example, let's assume your JNI function is:

```
JNI_EXPORT jboolean foobar(JNIEnv *env, jobject self) {
  ...
  return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

but you erroneously declare the Java counterpart as `public native Boolean foobar()` instead of `public native boolean foobar()`.

It's an easy mistake to make, since the only difference between `boolean` and `Boolean` is capitalization.

- `boolean`, a primitive type, is represented in JNI as `boolean`
- `java.lang.Boolean`, known also as `Boolean`, is a class type that is represented in JNI as `jobject`

Upon return from `foobar`, the Java VM will treat the `JNI_TRUE` value (0x1) as if it referred to a `java.lang.Boolean` object, which will result in this fatal error.

Answer (score 30):

The "stale local reference" error means that you're saving a local reference to some Java object between JNI calls; you need to convert that reference to a global reference using the `NewGlobalRef` method before doing anything that would  cause the reference to persist outside the scope of the one JNI call.

Although strictly this was *always* necessary -- it's in the JNI spec -- it's only since Ice Cream Sandwich that this actually causes problems on the Android platform.

Comment: Finally! . The reference's didnt seem to be the problem  , actually the real problem  was quite silly .In my c code a had a void function  but in java  i was declaring it as native float[]... Thank you for you help

Comment: @SteveL Thank you! I did the exact same thing (an early version of my native code returned a long, but I changed it to void in .c file and forgot to update in the .java.

Comment: If any of you have a chance to help me out i'm completely lost...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984132/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics

Comment: @Ernest mate i m new to android and facing the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423036/sqlite3-exception-database-disk-image-is-malformed pls tell how can i implement your code.. i m rectifying it from last 3 weeks :(

Answer (score 13):

@Ernest and @Ilya are correct. Note that the problem manifests itself in other ways too, not just signature mismatches. There is another very specific case that I ran into, which was explained [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html) in the Android' team's blog under the section:

> *Bug: Mistakenly assuming FindClass() returns global references*
>
> FindClass() returns local references. Many people assume otherwise. In a system without class unloading (like Android), you can treat jfieldID and jmethodID as if they were global. (They’re not actually references, but in a system with class unloading there are similar lifetime issues.) But jclass is a reference, and FindClass() returns local references. A common bug pattern is “static jclass”. Unless you’re manually turning your local references into global references, your code is broken.

Basically I was caching the `jclass` returned by `FindClass` in a global variable as is, but it turns out this value (as of Android 4?) is now a localref. As a result, I had to convert it into a globalref like so:

```
jclass jc = env->FindClass(callbacks.name);
// Since Android ICS, class references are not global so we need to peg a
// global reference to the jclass returned by FindClass(), otherwise we get
// following error in the log:
// "JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0xHHHHHHHH".
callbacks._class = static_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(jc));
```

After a lot of head-scratching, this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I've been through the same thing this week. I followed your solution and my crash was gone. On a side note: my test device (Asus Zenfone 2, running Android KitKat) did NOT present the issue, so I only saw the crash after the game went to Google Play and some friends installed it on Motorolas and Samsungs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on Ernest's answer, instead of passing a Boolean or even a boolean as an argument to the call method, I passed the literal true ( yes I did kick myself repeatedly when I found that) which of course has the value of 0x1.

Answer (score 0):

While not challenging the validity of the other answers, I lost hours chasing these errors. In my case they were truly cryptic but I've only myself to blame:

> 10-16 12:24:18.722: E/dalvikvm(1204): JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale global reference 0x26
>   10-16 12:24:18.722: E/dalvikvm(1204): VM aborting

For me, this meant I hadn't requested the correct permission in the manifest.

Comment: Which permission was that?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I missed passing some arguments required for the constructor(also may apply to calling methods) when calling `NewObject`.