# JNI error occurs sometimes in between while app is running

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm getting below JNI error.

```
E/dalvikvm(16831): JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale global reference 0x1d20043a
E/dalvikvm(16831): VM aborting
A/libc(16831): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000041bf (code=-6), thread 16831 (com.example.sample)
A/libc(16831): Send stop signal to pid:16831 in void debuggerd_signal_handler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
```

It occurs sometimes rarely and my app closes. Any suggestion about what this error is and what causes it?

Comment: You could check the answer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9978011/2688283).

Answer (score 0):

Your app meaning an app you made?

It usually occurs, as it says, when you attempt to use a global reference to a Java object in C or C++ code which is no longer valid.

If this is your app, then you have to check all of the global references you have created.

Comment: Yep app made by me. I'll check it out.

Comment: I have use '.so' file in app

Comment: You should check the question that @iRuth posted as a comment in your question, see if those help. But otherwise you have to check you are using that native library correctly from their documentation.